# How to organize user roles in a company model in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, roles

I have a rails application and I would like to implement user roles(permissions) in my application.
Basically in the application there is a Company model and a User model. I would like Company to have Owner-Users and Manager-users. For this I am planning to implement a Role model and a Permission model. `Role name:string` `Permission references:user, references:company, references:role`. But as a newbee in rails I would like to know if this is a good practice? What would be a better practice?

Comment: Probably using Rolify gem would save some time and effort: https://github.com/RolifyCommunity/rolify

Comment: other alternative is using cancancan gem, this is link https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

Comment: I like to use both the Rolify and cancancan together, ie `can :manage, Model if user.has_role?(:administrator)` or something like that